# Most Powerful Test Among Two Distributions (Hypothesis Testing / Decision Rule)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

> Assume that $X$ is a discrete random variable.  Based on an observed value of $X$, derive the most powerful test of $H_0:X\sim GEO(1-\lambda)$ vs $H_a: X\sim POI(\lambda)$ for a given value of $\alpha$, and find the power of this test.

If we take the ratio of the alternative distribution to the null, we'll find that:

$$\frac{f_a(x)}{f_0(x)}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{(1-\lambda)x!}$$

But in order to derive the randomized decision rule, I need to know the distribution of $X!$ under the null hypothesis.  Clearly there's an issue with this, so I must be missing something.  Surely something's wrong here, and if not, then I'm just completely lost.

**So what is the decision rule for this most powerful test, and how can you derive it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The randomized decision rule dictates accepting the alternative hypothesis necessarily if the likelihood ratio is greater than some constant $c$, and with some probability $p$ if this ratio is equal to this constant. And $C$ and $p$ are s.t. 
$$
\alpha = \mathbb P_0\left(\frac{f_a(X)}{f_0(X)}>c\right)+p\mathbb P_0\left(\frac{f_a(X)}{f_0(X)}=c\right).
$$
Consider the values of likelihood ratio for $X=0,1,2,\ldots$:
$$
\frac{f_a(0)}{f_0(0)}=\frac{f_a(1)}{f_0(1)}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-\lambda}, \ \frac{f_a(2)}{f_0(2)}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{2(1-\lambda)}, \ \frac{f_a(3)}{f_0(3)}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{6(1-\lambda)}, \ldots
$$
The likelihood ratio can take only these values. So we do not need to take other values of $c$ than $c=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!(1-\lambda)}$. Note also that the likelihood ratio is monotone function of $X$ for $X\geq 2$, and for $X=0$ and $1$ the values of l.r. are equal.

For any $k\geq 2$
$$
\mathbb P_0\left(\frac{f_a(X)}{f_0(X)}>\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!(1-\lambda)}\right)=\mathbb P_0(X<k)=1-\lambda^k.
$$
And if $\alpha\geq 1-\lambda^2$, then we can find $k\geq 2$ s.t.
$$\mathbb P_0(X<k)\leq\alpha <\mathbb P_0(X\leq k).$$
Solve these inequalities and find that $k=\left\lfloor\frac{\ln(1-\alpha)}{\ln\lambda}\right\rfloor$ bounds the critical region from above. The randomization probability $p$ can be found as
$$
\alpha = \mathbb P_0(X<k)+p\mathbb P_0(X=k) = 1-\lambda^k+p(1-\lambda)\lambda^k, \quad p=\frac{\alpha-(1-\lambda^k)}{(1-\lambda)\lambda^k}.
$$

The case $0<\alpha<1-\lambda^2$ corresponds to $c=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-\lambda}$. The inequality $\frac{f_a(X)}{f_0(X)}>c$ is impossible now. 
And 
$$
\frac{f_a(X)}{f_0(X)}=c \iff X=0 \vee 1, 
$$
$$
\mathbb P_0\left(\frac{f_a(X)}{f_0(X)}=c\right)=\mathbb P_0(X=0)+\mathbb P_0(X=1)=1-\lambda^2.
$$
So, this case the test reject null hypothesis with probability 
$$
p = \frac{\alpha}{1-\lambda^2}
$$

Finally, the UMP test with type-1 error $\alpha\geq 1-\lambda^2$ looks like
$$
\varphi(X)=\begin{cases}1, & X< k,\cr 
p, & X=k, \cr
0, & X> k,
\end{cases} \ \text{ where } k=\left\lfloor\frac{\ln(1-\alpha)}{\ln\lambda}\right\rfloor, \ p=\frac{\alpha-(1-\lambda^k)}{(1-\lambda)\lambda^k}.
$$

For $\alpha<1-\lambda^2$ UMP test looks like
$$
\varphi(X)=\begin{cases}
p, & X=0 \text{ or } 1, \cr
0, & X\geq 2,
\end{cases} \ \text{ where } p=\frac{\alpha}{1-\lambda^2} .
$$

Comment: Absolutely phenomenal work; seeing this example worked out has really helped me to understand how this works.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi NCh. Could you explain how this equation works $\mathbb P_0\left(\frac{f_a(X)}{f_0(X)}>\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!(1-\lambda)}\right)=\mathbb P_0(X<k)$? I know that $P_0$ means we assume the $H_0$ is true so $X \sim GEO(1-\lambda)$. Why could you conclude that it equals to $\mathbb P_0(X<k)$?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев For $k\geq 2$, $\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}}{X!(1-\lambda)}>\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!(1-\lambda)}$ iff $X<k$.